# jQuery validator addMethod() with callback method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I'm creating a user register form. I have one email textbox and I'm trying to test whether user's email is already exist in database or not.

Here is my validation function :

```
this.isEmailNotExist = function(mail,callback){
    var result = false;
    var mailEn = enCryptURL(mail);
    var isExist = getURL() + WebConfig.RACustomer + "?$filter=WebAccount eq '" + mailEn + "'";

    ajaxRequestCallback(isExist,"GET","json","application/json",function(customer){
        if(customer.length <= 0) {
            result = true;
        }else{
            result = false;
        }
        callback(result);
    });
};
```

Then I've added it to jquery validator method :

```
   $.validator.addMethod(
            "isEmailExist",
            function(value) {
                var cl = new CanvasLoader('register-canvasloader-container');
                cl.setDiameter(17);
                cl.setDensity(13);
                cl.setRange(1.7);
                cl.setSpeed(1);
                cl.setFPS(20);
                cl.show();

                _customer.isEmailNotExist(value,function(result){
                    cl.hide() ;
                    return result;
                });
            }
    );

$("#registerForm").validate({
   onkeyup: false,
   rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        maxlength: 30,
        isEmailExist : true
      }
   },
   messages: {
      email: {
        email : "Please enter a valid email address",
        isEmailExist : "This email is already existed"
      }
   }
  });
 });
```

Problem : After I entered email in text box, `This email is already existed` is shown without executing `isEmailExist` function that I've just added in jquery validation method.

How to solve this problem without adding `async : false` in ajax calling.

**Updated** : After got few answers, here I did :

```
$("#registerForm").validate({
  rules: {
      email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                maxlength: 30,
                remote: {
                    url:getURL() + "?$filter=email eq '" + $('#email') + "'",
                    type:'GET',
                    dataType:'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(response){
                        if(response.length > 0){
                            console.log("user is existed");
                            return false;
                        }else{
                            console.log("new user");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I've got one error `Cannot read property 'length' of null`.

Comment: find a sample of an ajax based rule... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9jt4A/1/

Comment: also see http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-ajax-validation-remote-rule/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, why are you creating a custom `remote` method when this plugin already has a working `remote` method built into it?  OP, the `remote` method is exactly for this sort of thing.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: You need to write a clear and concise question.  Many will be hesitant to answer if it's unclear or keeps changing every time you try something new.  Meanwhile, you don't need the `type`, `dataType` or `contentType` options as your values are already the defaults for the `remote` method.  You also do not need the `success` option as the `remote` method already handles the server response automatically.  In other words, you should only need the `url` option and nothing else.  `remote:  {your url here}`.  Refer to the link I already posted:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: @Sparky : what if I don't have the url to check but get the result whether user is existed in database or not.

Comment: @Nothing what the the value returned from the server

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking me.  If you use the `remote` method, then you'll need to specify the URL to the server-side script, otherwise, there's no point to any of this.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: JSON of user object.

Comment: @Sparky sorry for inconvenience and my bad explanation.. um... I do have a url from web service to get the customer object by the value that user fills in text box. But I wonder and just wanna know how to validate that text box by the url I had. Let me know if you don't get my point...

Comment: Nope, none of this is clear. Show us the server-side script in your OP and tell us what language you're using, PHP, etc?  How to validate that text box by the URL you have?  I just told you... `remote: url` and take a look at the documentation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/  ~ how exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I am using backbone.js with RESTful. Then I can get the data from web service by passing email's customer to url. So, if I get records back from web service, it means, customer is already existed.